# calender popup how to show server date

Tags: asp.net, calendar, ajaxcontroltoolkit

[image: calenderExtenderControl]

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBirthDate" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" onkeydown="return txtBirthDate_OnKeyDown();"
                    class="csstextbox" runat="server" Width="175px"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:CalendarExtender ID="calendarBirthDate" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="calendarBirthDate_DateSelectionChanged"
                    runat="server" Enabled="True" 
                    TargetControlID="txtBirthDate" Format="dd-MMM-yyyy">
                </asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Showing in calender popup client date i have to show server date.(This is client date "Today:November 13,2012")